# Problems with jqplot legend

Tags: charts, jqplot, legend

I am using jqplot. I am facing some issue with the legends.
The legend is overlapping some part of the chart. Also the legend is stretched to the full width of the chart.

Here's how it looks.
[image]

This makes it look ugly.
Can anyone help me out of this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a CSS problem. Just remove all your custom CSS (or JQPlot CSS modification) and add it step by step to find the guilty

Comment: Anyone else who have had similar issues? And got it fixed?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was in the CSS. I had already declared

```
table { width: 100%; }
```

So I added:

```
.jqplot-table-legend { width: auto; }
```

And that fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this trick from this forum

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jqplot-users/2ugbIYORAss

```
   //Take out HTML content of entire legend
    var text = jQuery("table[class='jqplot-table-legend']").html();

    //Stick it to the Legend Div Tag - of page
    //create a div tag with id='jqplotctrl_legend'
    jQuery('#jqplotctrl_legend').html(text); 

    //Set original jQPlot legend to empty 
    jQuery("table[class='jqplot-table-legend']").html('');
```